# how to execute double quoted string in wget command in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new on shell script so please understand if i missing somthing

I have this veriable in shell script `FILE_URR=$(echo "'http://localhost:8080/api/test/process?start_from_line=$START_FROM_LINE&source_file_id=$SOURCE_FILE_ID&hname=$HNAME&delimiter=$DELIMITER&input_file_name=$INPUT_FILE_NAME&start_from_line=$START_FROM_LINE&mappings=$MAPPINGS' -O /dev/null")`

if i run `echo $FILE_URR` this command i am getting output as `'http://localhost:8080/api/test/process?start_from_line=2&source_file_id=1234&hname=DHack&delimiter=,&input_file_name=husers.csv&start_from_line=2&mappings={"1":["skipColumn"],"2":["firstname"],"3":["lastname"],"4":["email"],"5":["skipColumn"],"6":["ipaddress"]}' -O /dev/null`

now i want to execute wget `$FILE_URR` command but it is showing Scheme missing error
but if i copy past above output with wget then it is working fine
.I think it is because of double quotes i dont know how to do this please any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `'` ones and it will work.